# If Statement for if the most previous specific word is found

Tags: excel, search, vba

I have converted data from a text file to excel in a way that each word has its own cell. The data is a list and the heading of each of the repsective list data is found in column E.

The amount of data is random in the fact that there may be 10 data points under the 1st heading but then 30 under the next.

My end goal is to have a excel sheet that has the data under neat headings. I have most of it all put together but what ai am trying to do is use a loop to count down all the rows and  if "apples" is found to be the most previous fruit type in column E then past the respective data on a different sheet. The issue I am having is the counting up to the preivous word i believe. Here is the code i am using for that part.

```
If Fruit.Range(E1, "E" & i).Find(what:="apples", _
                          searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                          searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row Then
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's not clear from your one line of code what you're trying to do here.  Your code will error though if "apples" is not found.

Comment: I have thought about the question. The simplist way i can say what i want to do is: count up column E and if " apples" appears do this.... In terms of if apples is not found thats ok. Im testing in an environment ahere it will always show up

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if "apples" was found or not in a range:

```
Dim f As Range

Set f = Fruit.Range("E1:E" & i).Find(what:="apples", _
                          searchorder:=xlByRows, _
                          searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
If Not f Is Nothing Then
    'do stuff
End If
```

Comment: Yes! This is so close. But i only want you find the first instance of the type of fruit. Example: i have headings of apples, bananas and oranges. Right now everything is being called an apple because its the 1st heading of the list

Comment: Ok but we have no idea what you're really trying to do here.  *If you want specific help* it would be a good idea to (1) show the rest of your code and (2) show an example before/after set of data

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do, but I think this will let you solve your problem (necessary comments in code):

```
Sub MyMacro()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, lastCol As Long, lastRow As Long
    'determine last row in E column
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    'loop thorugh E column
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        'perform case-insensitive search
        If InStr(1, LCase(Cells(i, 5).Value), "apple") > 0 Then
            'determine last column in a row
            lastCol = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            'loop through row
            For j = 6 To lastCol
                'do something with values in a row
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```